# Toggle the div with a button and hide the div when click outside of that div

Tags: jquery

I have a menu which I'm trying to toggle with a button (Which I've been able to do quit easily). But I also want menu to hide when clicked outside of it, And after lot of Googling I came across this solution. It works well i.e If you click outside the div, it hides it. But now I can't toggle the div with toggle button.

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
});



$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var container = $(".menu");

  // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
  if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    container.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.list,
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  Toggle
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Friends</li>
    <li>Family</li>
    <li>College</li>
    <li>Colleague</li>
    <li>Acquaintances</li>
    <li>Unsorted</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would really be greatful if alteast any one could explain to me what this line of code is actually doing.

```
container.has(e.target).length === 0
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this, hope it helps:

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu').toggle();
});
$('body :not(.menu, ul.list, li, .toggle)').click(function(e) {
    $(".menu").hide();
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.list,
{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  Toggle
</div>
<div>Click</div>
<div>any</div>
<div>element</div>
<div>to</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>only</div>
<div>affect</div>
<div>toggle and menu classes</div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Friends</li>
    <li>Family</li>
    <li>College</li>
    <li>Colleague</li>
    <li>Acquaintances</li>
    <li>Unsorted</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s29ppsbd/

The red area is the doc, the yellow area is the menu container.

The condition does exactly what it says in the comment that can be seen in the snippet, it checks if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container.

You are interested in toggler clicks as well as menu item clicks, instead of expanding the condition, I decided to wrap everything in a div with the class `menu-container`, if a click event comes from that and children of it (menu items themselves), it will not close the menu, otherwise, it will.

Closing the menu immediately as soon as a menu item was clicked on is a matter of choice, I personally don't like sites that immediately close the menu when I click a link, I get confused for 1 second, til I see the loading icon of the browser.